# remove the 29th of February from a dataframe with date index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, drop

I have this dataframe:

```
1/1/1990,1.9
1/2/1990,1.9
1/29/1990,1.9
1/4/1990,1.7775
1/5/1990,1.76
1/6/1990,1.76
1/7/1990,1.76
1/8/1990,1.76
1/1/1991,1.9
1/2/1991,1.9
1/29/1991,1.9
1/4/1991,1.7775
2/5/1991,1.76
2/6/1991,1.76
1/7/1991,1.76
3/29/1991,1.76
4/30/1991,1.76
```

proxy of a bigger database.

I would like to drop all the data referring to the 29th of February.

This is how I read the dataframe:

```
dfr = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

this is the best solution that I have found so far:

```
dfr = dfr.loc[~(dfr.index.month==2 & dfr.index.day==29)]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Int64Index'
```

It is strange, because `dfr.index.month==2` as well as `dfr.index.day==29` work. I have the feeling that they have to be converted to pandas date but I do not know how.

Answer (score 3):

Your parentheses are incorrect as `&` has higher [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `==`.

Your expression is equivalent to `~(dfr.index.month == (2 & dfr.index.day) == 29)`, which triggers the error `unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'Int64Index'`.

You need to use:

```
dfr = dfr.loc[~((dfr.index.month==2) & (dfr.index.day==29))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use `strftime` for a solution without hassling of parantheses:

```
dfr[dfr.index.strftime('%m-%d') != '02-29']
```